# ListView Footer positioning changes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added a footer to ListView and then reset the adapter. In all cases the list is empty, but I notice that sometimes the footer appears lower and sometimes higher in the ListView.   Basically I am just showing a TextView with a message, but sometimes I have to use scroll up to see the FooterView even though in all cases the ListView does not contain list items.  Is there a way to pin the footer to the top?

Comment: This post has been artificially downvoted. Please upvote if you see this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the whole list was repositioning within the layout.  The whole empty list that is. Fix was to use relative layout to contain the whole ListView and align ListView with the top of Relative Layout.

Answer (score 1):

Take look on this code, it worked for me.

```
private View footerView;
```

---

```
ListView lv = (ListView) main_activity.findViewById(R.id.listView);
if (footerView != null)
    lv.removeFooterView(footerView);

adapter = new ArrayList();
setAdapterList();    // fill data in the arrayList

footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
if (adapter.size() != 0) {
    lv.addFooterView(footerView);
    setFooterView(footerView);     // set data in the footer
}
lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(main_activity));
```

Comment: why if (adapter.size != 0) ?, in my case I want to show error  message in footer view when there is no data.

Comment: Ok then show the error message `if(adapter.size() == 0)` my footerview  does not appear lower and sometimes higher in the ListView, as you asked.